# Non-parallel for loop in a parallel block

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a parallel block, which spawns a certain amount of threads. All of these threads then should start a "shared" for loop which contains multiple parallel for loops. For example something like this:

```
// 1. The parallel region spawns a number of threads.
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // 2. Each thread does something before it enters the loop below.
    doSomethingOnEachThreadAsPreparation();

    // 3. This loop should run by all threads synchronously; i belongs 
    // to all threads simultaneously
    // Basically there is only one variable i. When all threads reach this
    // loop i at first is set to zero.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // 4. Then each thread calls this function (this happens in parallel)
        doSomethingOnEachThreadAtTheStartOfEachIteration();

        // 5. Then all threads work on this for loop in parallel
        #pragma omp for
        for (int k = 0; i < 100000000; k++)
            doSomethingVeryTimeConsumingInParallel(k);
        // 6. After the parallel for loop there is (always) an implicit barrier 

        // 7. When all threads finished the for loop they call this method in parallel.
        doSomethingOnEachThreadAfterEachIteration();

        // 8. Here should be another barrier. Once every thread has finished
        // the call above, they jump back to the top of the for loop, 
        // where i is set to i + 1. If the condition for the loop
        // holds, continue at 4., otherwise go to 9. 
    }

    // 9. When the "non-parallel" loop has finished each thread continues.
    doSomethingMoreOnEachThread();
}
```

I thought it might already be possible to implement this type of behaviour using
`#pragma omp single` and a shared `i` variable, but I am not certain of that anymore.

What the functions actually do is irrelevant; this is about the control flow. I added comments as to how I *want* it to be.
If I understand it correctly, the loop at `3.` would normally create an `i` variable for each thread and the loop head is generally not executed only by a single thread. But this is what I want for this case.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "run by all threads synchronously". It's not clear why you want `i` to be shared and what you actually mean by that. The problem with your pseudocode example is that we know not enough about all the functions you call.

Comment: Your explanation are not clear.  What do you mean by `doSomethingMoreOnEachThreadButOnlyOnce`? omp single will execute a block only on a thread, not the block only once on every thread.  If you want the latter, you should check the value of a local var (just like in sequential programming). Unrelated, but the second omp parallel is only meaningful if you use open mp nested parallelism or hand control the number of threads.

Comment: @Zulan I added some further clarifications.

Comment: @AlainMerigot What the functions do does not matter, this is only about the control flow for the parallelization/the loops. (And I removed the "parallel" from the inner for loop.)

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at OpenMP tasking and the way it supports ordering execution of tasks via task dependences.

Comment: What the functions do **does matter** and this is why the question cannot yet be properly answered. You describe a very specific control flow which may very well be the wrong approach to your actual problem - but we cannot tell (XY-problem). Now the way I understand your desired control flow can be trivially implemented by just using a private `i` because then each value of `i` is always the same for each thread. But then again we cannot know whether that is even correct without knowing how the functions interact with shared state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `for` loop in all threads. Depending on your algorithm a synchronization will probably be required either after every iteration (as below) or at the end of all iterations.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  // enter parallel region
  doSomethingOnEachThreadAsPreparation();
    //done in // by all threads

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        doSomethingOnEachThreadAtTheStartOfEachIteration();
#       pragma omp for
        // parallelize the for loop
        for (int k = 0; i < 100000000; k++)
            doSomethingVeryTimeConsumingInParallel(k);
        // implicit barrier

        doSomethingOnEachThreadAfterEachIteration();
#       pragma omp barrier
        // Maybe a barrier is required, 
        // so that all iterations are synchronous
        // but if it is not required by the algorithm
        // performances will be better without the barrier
    }

    doSomethingMoreOnEachThread();
    // still in parallel
}
```

As pointed out by Zulan, enclosing the main `for` loop by an `omp single` to re-enter later a parallel section does not work, unless you use nested parallelism. In that case, threads would be recreated at every iteration and this would cause a major slow down.

```
omp_set_nested(1);
#pragma omp parallel
{
  // enter parallel region
  doSomethingOnEachThreadAsPreparation();
    //done in // by all threads

# pragma omp single
  // only one thread runs the loop
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
#     pragma omp parallel
      {
        // create a new nested parallel section
        // new threads are created and this will 
        // certainly degrade performances
        doSomethingOnEachThreadAtTheStartOfEachIteration();
#       pragma omp for
        // and we parallelize the for loop
        for (int k = 0; i < 100000000; k++)
            doSomethingVeryTimeConsumingInParallel(k);
        // implicit barrier

        doSomethingOnEachThreadAfterEachIteration();
      }
      // we leave the parallel section (implicit barrier)
    }
    // we leave the single section

    doSomethingMoreOnEachThread();
    // and we continue running in parallel
}
```

Comment: Creating a nested parallel section is a bad idea. Not only will this have horrible performance in many default runtime configurations, but it also means that whatever `doSomethingOnEachThreadAsPreparation` did was not done on the threads that are doing the actual inner work.

Comment: @Zulan This is *not* nested parallelism. The parallel block is within a single region and just reenters enclosing parallel region. So there is no problem to reuse whatever work was done by the threads. Note that this behavior happens, even is if OMP_SET_NESTED is set: no new threads are created. Of course, this would be completely different is this was done within a parallel region.

Comment: The only drawback of the first solution vs the second is that thread local variables are reset when reentering the parallel region within the single. But besides that they are equivalent (though I suspect the first one to be slightly slower).

Comment: I don't believe OpenMP makes any attempt to reuse an enclosing parallel region. At least I can't find anything regarding that in `2.6`. This is also confirmed by an [example code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uuWA3KhFCFXUfMrj). Have you ran some test code? Can you refer to a specific paragraph in the standard that suggests that a `parallel` clause within a `single` does *not*  create a *new* team of threads?

Comment: I did some tests. However, I had OMP_SET_NESTED for other experiments and it was a major flaw. It worked, but is was nested parallelism, which is of course not a good idea. So you are right and the only way to reenter a parallel section is through nesting. Thanks for pointing out. I update the answer accordingly.